# Compare Date with Current Date using SQL in MS Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

I have a table in ms access 2013. It has a column name expirydate having date values. I need to write a query with the following condition
expirydate is greater than current date.
Can anyone tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing that you can use SQL query :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE expirydate > Date()
```