# Sql Expression to Filter Records That has the Current System Date

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have a VB application and MS Access Database as BackEnd. I want to display all the Records on my db to Datagrid that has the of current system date.
I'm having a problem on my sql statement I don't know how should I do it.

It is displaying an error "Dataype Mismatch in Criteria Expression"

```
  sqlqry = "Select * FROM tblAttendance WHERE WorkingDate >= '#" & 
                           DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() & "#'"    
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlqry, cnn)   
    Dim dt As New DataTable("tblAttendance")
    da.Fill(dt)
    Me.dgvAttendance.DataSource = dt
    DataGridProperty(dgvAttendance)
    DataGridAttendance(dgvAttendance)
```

Comment: remove the single quotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare Date with Current Date using SQL in MS Access 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22895095/compare-date-with-current-date-using-sql-in-ms-access-2013)

Comment: Remove the entire date expression and use the built-in `Date()` function eg `WHERE WorkingDate()>=Date()`. You should avoid using string concatenation at all costs too, as this exposes you both to SQL injection attacks , bad performance *and* format mismatches - `ToShortDateString` uses the current system's locale which probably *doesn't* match the date literal format.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, Thanks to you, it really works, a very good advice to avoid sql injection, I will note it.   sqlqry="SELECT * FROM tblAttendance WHERE WorkingDate = Date()"

Answer (score 2):

Probably there is a problem with passing `DateTime` as string to your query.

My advice would be to use parameter, as OleDB integration will take care for properly passing arguments to MS Access

```
Dim sqlqry As String = "Select * FROM tblAttendance WHERE WorkingDate >= ?"
Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlqry, cnn)

da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("@WorkingDate", DateTime.Now))

Dim dt As New DataTable("tblAttendance")
da.Fill(dt)
Me.dgvAttendance.DataSource = dt
DataGridProperty(dgvAttendance)
DataGridAttendance(dgvAttendance)
```

Writing from my head, but this should do.

Comment: Good advice, although the current date specifically can be returned by the  `Date()` function.

Answer (score -2):

This should do:

```
sqlqry = "Select * FROM tblAttendance WHERE WorkingDate = #" & DateTime.ToDay.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") & "#"
```